# rails S3 subfolders with refile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, refile

I have a rails 4 app. I'm trying to make a subfolder system on S3 for different refile uploaders. I tried the code below but it didn't work out. Nothing got uploaded to S3 nor got displayed in the app.

What did I miss?

The logs:

```
20:24:09 puma.1    | Started GET "/attachments/refile_caches_backend/presign?t=1459707849942.0" for ::1 at 2016-04-03 20:24:09 +0200
20:24:10 puma.1    | Refile::App: [2016-04-03 20:24:10 +0200] GET "/refile_caches_backend/presign?t=1459707849942.0" 404 29.7ms
```

refile.rb

```
require "refile/s3"

aws = {
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  region: "us-east-1",
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}

message_files = aws.merge({bucket: "message_files"})
product_files = aws.merge({bucket: "product_files"})
refile_caches = aws.merge({bucket: "refile_caches"})

Refile.backends["message_files_backend"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "store", **message_files)
Refile.backends["product_files_backend"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "store", **product_files)
Refile.backends["refile_caches_backend"] = Refile::S3.new(max_size: 5.megabytes, prefix: "cache", **refile_caches)
Refile.cdn_host = ENV['CLOUDFRONT_URL']
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :message_attachment, store: 'message_files_backend', cache: 'refile_caches_backend' ,extension: ["pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "html", "png", "img", "jpg"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I couldn't configure the cache with `Refile.backends`, so I just left it as it was, since that part doesn't seem to be crucial.

For the storage the backend configuration works, files get uploaded to the desired subfolder.

```
Refile.backends["message_files_backend"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "store/message_files", **aws)
Refile.backends["product_files_backend"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "store/product_files", **aws)
Refile.cache = Refile::S3.new(max_size: 5.megabytes, prefix: "cache", **aws)

#in the model thanks to using the default cache it doesn't have to be defined
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :message_attachment, store: 'message_files_backend', extension: ["pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "html", "png", "img", "jpg"]
end
```